# Writing a homogeneous oscillator DE as a first-order vector DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, first-order-logic, oscillatory-integral

Trying to understand the connection between oscillations and vector DEs, how would I write the homogenous oscillator DE 
$$y’’+ 2\lambda y’ + w_0^2y = 0$$ as a first-order vector DE?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put $y'=v$ then $v' = -2\lambda v-w_o^2y$

Answer (score 0):

Set

$z =  y', \; z' = y''; \tag 1$

then the equation

$y'' + 2\lambda y' + \omega_0^2 y = 0 \tag 2$

becomes

$z' + 2\lambda z + \omega_0^2 y = 0, \tag 3$

that is,

$ z' = -2\lambda z - \omega_0^2 y; \tag 4$

if we now define

$\mathbf r = \begin{pmatrix} y \\ z \end{pmatrix}, \tag 5$

then

$\mathbf r' = \begin{pmatrix} y' \\ z' \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} z \\ -2\lambda z - \omega_0^2 y   \end{pmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -\omega_0^2 & -2\lambda \end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -\omega_0^2 & -2\lambda \end{bmatrix} \mathbf r.    \tag 6$

We have thus reduced the second-order *scalar* equation (2) to the first-order *linear* vector system

$\mathbf r^\prime =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -\omega_0^2 & -2\lambda \end{bmatrix} \mathbf r,  \tag 7$

as per request.